# Is there a media center extender app for Android?

Tags: media-player, video

Is there an app that will work as a Windows or Linux media center extender?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[HomePipe is one such service.](https://www.homepipe.net/)

[Subsonic is an open source server / web based solution](http://www.subsonic.org/pages/index.jsp).

A free alternative solution is [ampcache](http://ampache.org/) / [amdroid](http://www.appbrain.com/app/amdroid/com.sound.ampache)